# FB.logout callback not firing when using extended access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have extended access token but my `FB.logout` not working. Here is my code-

```
function ActionLogout()
{
   Connecting('show', 'Running Logout ...', 0);
   FB.logout(function(response) {
      dataString = "access_token={{access_token}}";
      $.ajax({  
         type: "GET",
         url: "{{path}}/logout",                  
         data: dataString,  
         success: function(txt) {
            window.location = "{{path}}";
         }  
      });
   });
}
```

My ajax call never happen so callback never firing. How to logout user from my app and facebook when I have extended access token. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `response` of the call.

Comment: @SahilMittal i said it's not callback when i try to alert or console.log response it's not reachable code cuz callback function never fire

Comment: Well this isnt possible. There must be some error thrown somewhere- may be in the browser's console or `response` in the callback.